# Where to specify --module flag in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using the brand new Visual Studio Code editor for some TypeScript. And, trying to import some classes from a `d.ts` like this:

```
import Polygon = require('esri/geometry/Polygon');
```

But, I'm getting a red squiggly that says:

```
Cannot compile external dependencies unless the --module flag is provided
```

My question is, where do I provide that flag? I believe it's a flag to the TypeScript compiler. In Visual Studio, it's a checkbox on the project. But in Code, I can't find any editor setting for that.

Comment: can you provide a sample of your now working tsconfig.json? I have it compiling/running OK using mine but I still get red line under require(). thanks

Comment: nevermind.. turns out VS Code needed restarting to reload the config. I'm seeing that pattern quite a bit with VS Code requiring restarts after config changes,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> But in Code, I can't find any editor setting for that.

You need to use `tsconfig.json` : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md

Comment: That was my first guess, actually. It turns out, there was an error in my tsconfig, and that's why it wasn't working. The error was that I had comments in the file -- duh -- invalid json.

Comment: so how to add the --modules flag ?

Comment: @NassimMOUALEK `"module" : "commonjs"`

Comment: How do you keep the tsconfig up to date when adding more files to VS Code? The files list specifically.

Comment: Don't use `files`. And that implies *all files*

Answer (score 16):

I just want to call out the fact that restarting the editor is an important step.  I created a tsconfig.json and bashed my head against the wall for a while before I noticed the comment by antfx, and sure enough, restarting VS Code solved the problem.